# Сложный SQL запрос по выборке (поиск с массивом)

Tags: sql

Не могу понять как сделать 1 запрос к 3-м таблицам и получить нужные данные.
Попробую описать что нужно:

Есть 3 таблицы

1-я `shema` в ней связь разделов и подразделов поля:

```
id-auto | id_razdel | id_podrazdel
```

2-я `price` - (цены) поля:

```
id-auto | id_podrazdel | id_organization
```

3-я `organizations` - (организации) поля:

```
id_organization | name_org |
```

---

Что нужно:

взять из `shema` все `id_podrazdel` по запрошенному `id_razdel`, выбрать из таблицы `price` все `id_organization` соединив их с таблицей `organizations`.

т.е. на выходе у меня все организации (уникальные) которые входят во все подразделы запрошенного раздела и цены .
Поясню: чтобы у меня была одна организация, но со всеми ценами из таблицы price? (т.е. массив в массиве)?

Вот как-то так.

Подскажите как правильно организовать запрос?

Спасибо.

Comment: Уточните какая именно реализация SQL у вас?(MSSQL\MySQL\.....)

Answer (score 0):

Для MySQL(вероятно не только для него) так:

```
Select 
  organizations.id_organization,
  organizations.name_org,
  schema.id_podrazdel,
  shema.id_razdel
From 
  organizations
  join price on price.id_organization=organizations.id_organization
  join shema on schema.id_podrazdel = price.id_podrazdel
Where 
  shema.id_razdel='ID нужного раздела';
```

Если вам нужны уникальные организации, то нужно было это уточнять в вопросе, а вообще вот так:

```
Select 
  organizations.id_organization,
  organizations.name_org
From 
  organizations
  join price on price.id_organization=organizations.id_organization
  join shema on schema.id_podrazdel = price.id_podrazdel
Where 
  shema.id_razdel='ID нужного раздела'
Group By 
  name_org;
```

Comment: т.к. в таблице price много записей (т.е. одна организация фигурирует несколько раз) данный запрос выдает name_org одной и той же много раз. Как избавиться от дублирования?

Comment: @ПетровКирилл Обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Просто не понимал пока какой будет результат. Результат получил, но он меня не очень устраивает. Подскажите возможно ли сделать запрос так чтобы у меня была одна организация, но со всеми ценами из таблицы price? (т.е. массив в массиве)?

Comment: @ПетровКирилл Во первых приведите пример желаемого результата, во вторых движок субд.

Comment: @ПетровКирилл на mysql можно получить например список цен через запятую в одном поле, с помощью функции group_concat().  дргугих СУБД есть другие методы решения данной задачи. Но в любом случе - ответ запроса это таблица, двумерная, со строками и столбцами и количество столбцов всегда фиксировано. А список - это уже третье измерение и адекватно это представить в виде плоской таблицы невозможно (с точки зрения геометрии). Поэтому такие преобразования над данными производят уже там, где их используют

Comment: СУБД Mysql.  Я хотел получить название организации и список цен (их несколько на каждый подраздел), у цен есть еще названия услуг (все в таблице price) . И в пхп перебрать этот массив, чтобы упростить вывод.

Comment: @ПетровКирилл, как вам написал Mike, это можно реализовать с помощью group_concat, но я вам так делать не советовал бы.. если прям **очень надо**, то укажите в каком именно поле какой именно таблицы хранится цена.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `o`.`name_org` FROM `schema` AS `s`

LEFT JOIN `price` AS `p`
ON `s`.`id_podrazdel` = `p`.`id_podrazdel`

LEFT JOIN `organizations` AS `o`
ON `p`.`id_organization` = `o`.`id_organization`

WHERE `s`.`id_razdel` = 1;
```

Comment: т.к. в таблице price много записей (т.е. одна организация фигурирует несколько раз) данный запрос выдает name_org одной и той же много раз. Как избавиться от дублирования?

Comment: @ПетровКирилл обновил ответ

Comment: Отлично спасибо. Подскажите возможно ли сделать запрос так чтобы у меня была одна организация, но со всеми ценами из таблицы price? (т.е. массив в массиве)? Или тут уже sql не поможет?

Comment: Нет, SQL такое не делает. Только на уровне какой-либо ЯП.